# Why does the Community bot have 5 reputation?

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation

[The community bot](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has 5 reputation: why is this? Also, its Main User has 1 reputation, and only the Meta user has 5 reputation, which doesn't usually happen; even with people. Is this a bug?

Comment: note: this has been that way since quite a while: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230290/community-has-gone-crazy-on-code-review-meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Community user is special, as is explained on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/269301).

It's a bot operating on the entire network and it's reputation doesn't mean anything. For example: if you flag a question as spam the question is automatically downvoted as well. Somebody has to be responsible for that downvote, so it's attributed to Community. It doesn't have the reputation to do so, but that doesn't matter. It's a very special bot.

Community is active on every site. Community changed all Stack Exchange links from `http` to `https` inside posts when the support for it came on-line. It can reject edits, turn posts into a community wiki and a lot more.

Well, automated scripts do. And whenever actions need to be attributed to someone and it's done by an automatic script, it's attributed to Community.

Long story short: Community's reputation is irrelevant and it's not a bug. Simply a special case.

Have you noticed Community's user id?

Comment: I know everything, and yes: I have, it's -1.

Comment: But have you seen that it was "Last seen Jan 19 '11 at 19:31"?

Comment: The real confusion comes from why [Meta has 5 rep](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) and [Main has 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). This added with the fact you can't get or lose rep on Meta...

Comment: @Peilonrayz I suspect that's due to the minimum reputation required to be active on meta, although you'd have to ask the team to be sure. It's definitely not intuitive, one way or another. That's because Community is very, very special.

Comment: @Mast Since Community has [1 rep on SO.Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) and on [PPCG.Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), I guess it "is very, very special" is the only answer... ):